# Private method not there when we do javap classname

Tags: java, decompiling, javap

Why a private method is not there when i use `javap classname` on
console after compiling that java file?

```
class A
{
    private void one(){}
    public void two(){}
    protected void three(){}
}
```

Comment: In general you'll get more helpful answers if you're able to explain a little more context about why it matters. In this case the answer is essentially "because it doesn't". If you provide more information on the wider problem you're trying to solve that's hampered by not listing the private methods you're likely to get a bit more help in solving the original problem.

Answer (score 23):

Private methods are not displayed by default, you need to use:

```
javap -private A
```

Comment: yes its working but is there any particular reason for doing so?

Comment: Probably because the vast majority of use cases only require `public` & `protected` methods to be shown and therefore making `private` methods optional make sense :)

Comment: @Reimeus This answer worked for me! Looks like OP forgot about you though :p